# How to maintain chapter number references using MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I am numbering my chapters using automatic numbering like

1. chapter 1

1.1 Subchapter 1

1.2 Subchapter 2

2. chapter 2

... etc.

I have to use references to chapter numbers in my text like

"It is describer in detail in chapter 1.2"

I use cross-links for this. Unfortunately, when I insert new subchapter 1.2, current subchapter 1.2 is renumbered to 1.3 (which is OK), but my cross reference shows still 1.2, instead of renumbered 1.3. Is there a way, how to have these in-document references renumbered together with auto numbers change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [this](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283073&p=1888264) helps:

> When your caption number changes, you can update the in-text
>   references by right-clicking the in-text reference and selecting
>   Update field:

[image]

Comment: You can also select the entire document (CTRL+A) and press F9 to update all references.